# PHP 4 try catch alternative?

Tags: php, error-handling, php4

Could someone help me translate this code to PHP 4?

```
try
{
  $picture = PDF_open_image_file($PDF, "jpeg", $imgFile, "", 0); // This is the original statement, this works on PHP4
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
  $msg = "Error opening $imgFile for Product $row['Identifier']";
  throw new Exception($msg);
}
```

Basically when there is a fatal error I need to get the $row['Identifier'] so I know what product is causing the error.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I don't know what PHP_open_image_file does, but sometimes I get errors like below, and I need to get the product identifier that is causing the error.

> Fatal error: PDFlib error [1016]
>   PDF_open_image_file: Couldn't open
>   JPEG file 'picture/b01_le1x.jpg' for
>   reading (file not found) in
>   /var/www/html/catalogue/pdf_make.php 
>   on line 618

Comment: Why are you still using PHP4?

Comment: +1 The server for this thing is still using PHP4 =.="

Comment: My condolences. If `PDF_open_image_file` throws an exception, will it even run as-is in PHP4? Seems like you'd have to rearchitect the whole thing.

Comment: Tell your host to not suck and update to PHP5

Comment: And tell us who your host is so we can avoid them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming you are using [PDF_open_image_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-open-image-file.php) from the pdflib PECL extension?

If so, then it will never throw an exception on PHP 4. I would assume error states are reported through the result, which is an int and thus probably < 1 in case of errors.

```
//try
if (file_exists($imgFile)) {
    $picture = PDF_open_image_file($PDF, "jpeg", $imgFile, "", 0);
}

//catch
if (!$picture) {
   $msg = "Error opening $imgFile for Product $row['Identifier']";
   print $msg;
}
```

I've **updated** this with `file_exists` to prevent your fatal error.

As addendum question, why were you trying to rethrow an exception on PHP4?

Comment: Thanks Mario! I just wanted to add $row['Identifier'] to the error message, that's all I need to do. Your code will handle file not exist, but what if the JPEG file is corrupted? It's really not possible to catch the error is it?

Comment: I am not sure what PDF library it is. How would you handle the error states?

Comment: @aximili: Open the file first yourself to check (`imagecreatefromjpeg`). There is no error catching capability in PDFLib unless otherwise noted.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch some problems by setting a default error handler (see [PHP Manual entry](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)), but that won't let you catch E_ERRORS.

I don't think this will be possible in PHP4, you'll need to upgrade to PHP5 so it throws an exception instead of an E_ERROR. You may be able to catch certain errors before they happen - for example by running `file_exists()` on your input file, but you are unlikely to be able to think of and catch all the errors that PDFLib will.